# Watson Machine Learning (WML) Authentication Issue; WML working example (?)

Tags: authentication, watson-studio

I am experimenting with Watson Machine Learning (WML) as I would like to deploy a deep learning model through a web API. I have an issue regarding authentication.

I am following the IBM tutorials and I have an issue with the WML authentication. On the tutorial it is mentioned to provide the following credentials to deploy the model on WML:

```
wml_credentials = { "apikey"      : "***",
                    "url"         : "https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net",
                    "username"    : "***",
                    "password"    : "***",
                    "instance_id" : "***"
                   }
```

I fear that the information is outdated. When looking for the at the WML service credentials on IBM cloud I am provided with the following info:

```
{
  "apikey": "xxx",
  "iam_apikey_description": "xxx"
  "iam_role_crn": "xxx",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "xxx",
  "instance_id": "xxx",
  "url": "https://us-south.ml.cloud.ibm.com"
}
```

I get no username & passwd. Moreover the url is different to the one provided in the tutorial is different than the one provided on the tutorial. I tried to play with the python script but I get errors, which are diffcult to understand given that I have no idea of the structure of WML.

Can anyone provide a functioning script and some good intuition about the mechanism of working with WML. The tutorial is not very informative on what is happening under the hood and that makes it difficult to troubleshoot and get started with...

---

### [tutorial link](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-python-mnist-tutorial.html?audience=wdp)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Cloud if the wml instance is in us-south region, you can use the below.

wml_credentials = { 
                    "apikey"      : "***",
                    "url"         : "https://us-south.ml.cloud.ibm.com",
                    "instance_id" : "***"
                   }

The values for apikey, url and instance_id should be used from the wml instance credentials. (instance vcap)

The url differs based on the region where the wml instance has been created.

e.g for us-south it will be https://us-south.ml.cloud.ibm.com
for London it will be https://eu-gb.ml.cloud.ibm.com